# GROUP BY and SUM in EXCEL

Tags: excel, group-by, grouping

I have two columns in Excel.

**"NIP"** and **"HOW_MUCH"** 
*NIP* = client's NIP 
*HOW_MUCH* = How much he bought

There can be two or more rows of the same client (same NIP). 
How to **GROUP BY NIP** and get **SUM** of **"HOW_MUCH"** like in SQL?

If someone want to know, it looks like that:

872-13-44-365   10 
369-43-03-176   2 
408-24-90-350   2 
944-16-93-033   5 
645-32-78-780   14 
594-18-15-403   436 
043-34-53-278   95 
254-14-00-156   350 
254-14-00-156   231

Comment: Show what the source data looks like and what you have attempted so far to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pivottable and put HOW_MUCH in data/values area and NIP in row area making sure NIP is SUM of NIP.

Select a populated cell in the range and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to convert your data to a table, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, to create a pivottable from your table. Put NIP in bottom left row area, and HOW_MUCH in bottom right data/values area.

Data and pivot

[image: Data]